# Transparent or Green Background to Tikz (?) Image

Tags: latex, tikz

I am using the following code to generate some pictures of Venn Diagrams. I found the example below using the venndiagram package.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{venndiagram}

\begin{document}

          \begin{venndiagram3sets}

          \fillOnlyA

          \end{venndiagram3sets}

\end{document}
```

It works fine but I would like to either make the background transparent or green i.e. the images are going to be placed on a green background. Here is a screenshot of what it currently looks like:

Venn Diagram Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMguH.png

Also, is it possible to change the color of the text and circles (line color) for the Venn Diagrams?

Any help and advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If I run your code, I do get a pdf with transparent background.

[image]

However you can set the page colour explicitly:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}    
\usepackage{venndiagram} 
\pagecolor{green}    
    
\begin{document}   
    \begin{venndiagram3sets}  
    \fillOnlyA    
    \end{venndiagram3sets}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can we apply pagecolor to A as well?

Comment: @alper If you don't want to fill A, don't use `\fillOnlyA`

Comment: In some cases I have to write a label on top of a arrow, which requires white background

Comment: @alper ... then maybe you should ask a question about your specific problem?